# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API post method causing 405 "Method Not Allowed" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Newbie here trying to create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API for the first time.

My `GET` method is working fine but whenever I try the `POST` method I get a 405 "Method Not Allowed" error. I searched and searched and most solutions seem to be centered around disabling webDAV is the `web.config` file or using the proper route path.

I'm running locally for now trying to test directly out of Visual Studio 2019 so no `web.config` exists. I'm submitting the `POST` request using Postman to the URL `http://localhost:58322/api/test/` where port 58322 is the assigned port when running the project.

Can someone please tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Here is my code for `TestController.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SimpleAPI.Models;

namespace SimpleAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly appDBContext _context;

        public TestController(appDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Test
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Test>>> GetTest()
        {
            return await _context.Test.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Test/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> GetTest(int id)
        {
            var test = await _context.Test.FindAsync(id);

            if (test == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return test;
        }

        // PUT: api/Test/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutTest(int id, Test test)
        {
            if (id != test.DataId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TestExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Test
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> PostTest(Test test)
        {
            _context.Test.Add(test);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTest), new { id = test.DataId }, test);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Test/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> DeleteTest(int id)
        {
            var test = await _context.Test.FindAsync(id);
            if (test == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Test.Remove(test);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return test;
        }

        private bool TestExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Test.Any(e => e.DataId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Model class named test.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SimpleAPI.Models
{
    public partial class Test
    {
        public int DataId { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SimpleAPI.Models;

namespace SimpleAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDatabase");
            services.AddDbContext<appDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Test}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDatabase": "Server=server;Database=dbname;User ID=user;Password=***;"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure your problem but I suspect the anti forgery token may be the issue. Put the attribute `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]` on your POST method and try that

Comment: Probably CORS related. Read up on CORS and how to enable in startup.cs.
Also, Postman can be confusing at first, make sure your request contains the "Test" payload as json in the body.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I couldn't reproduce your complaint; just made a new API project, put your code in it, stripped it down to just `Ok()` responses and the post worked fine

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I tried adding the anit forgery token, enabled CORS in startup, and added the [FromBody] attribute.  None of those seemed to help.  I then stripped down the post method to simply public void Post() and it seems to like that.  So maybe an issue with the way I'm submitting through Postman?  I change it to POST method with the path http://localhost:58322/api/test and in the Body I use raw format with JSON as { "data" : "testing" }

Comment: Got it!  It was the format I was using in Postman.  I was sending in raw format but did not notice the dropdown that defaults to "Text".  Switched it to "JSON" and it worked as expected.  Thank you all for helping out!  Figured it was something in the code.  With your great guidance was able to narrow it down.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you get a MethodNotAllowed when the webapp can't find the Method.

Change your post to this and see if that works:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> PostTest([FromBody] Test test)
    {
        _context.Test.Add(test);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTest), new { id = test.DataId }, test);
    }
```

Comment: How [FromBody] attribute is related to route discovery?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov When working on my .NET Core projects it sometimes gave me a 405 when I didn't add the [FromBody] attribute. My answer is just a suggestion and not a guaranteed solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was more an issue with Postman than with the code.  Great comments guided me to look at how the data was being sent with Postman.  Comment by Max in particular was right on the money.